# Dojo 1.10 iFrame to access another website

Tags: iframe, dojo

I am new to DOJO and have a requirement where in we need to embed already running website on our new website using an iframe. Both websites will be running on same domain.

I tried using dojo/request/iframe, and am able to see the website in my iframe BUT when clicking on any of the link in embedded website, it opens in another window. But i want it to work in my iframe internally.

Below is the code snippet:

```
<script>


          require(["dojo/request/iframe", "dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct"], function(iframe, dom, domConst){
      iframe("http://localhost:8080/phpkbv8/", {
         handleAs: "html"
          }).then(function(data){
            var greetingNode = dom.byId('siteInclude');
            domConst.place(data.documentElement,greetingNode);
          }, function(err){
            var greetingNode = dom.byId('siteInclude');
            domConst.place('<p>Error Occured!!!</p>' + err,greetingNode);
          });
          // Progress events are not supported using the iframe provider
        });
        </script>
```

Please help me in making it work. Looking for help.

Comment: hi and welcom on so. Please create a a jsfiddle showing your problem or add your error from the console here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are intending to embed an iframe into your page for display/interaction purposes, you shouldn't really be using `dojo/request/iframe` to do so.  If you need to create the iframe programmatically, use DOM APIs or `dojo/dom-construct`.  For example, based on your code above:

```
domConst.create('iframe', {
    src: 'http://localhost:8080/phpkbv8/'
}, greetingNode);
```

`dojo/request/iframe` is specifically intended as a transport for sending Ajax requests, in cases where XHR, script injection, etc. aren't sufficient.